# Conditionally mock httputil.get method on specific url with path json

Tags: python, unit-testing, http, mocking, patch

I have http `get` method mocked so to get the response from the url without actually sending the url:

```
def get(url, retries=None, back_off_factor=None, max_back_off=None, timeout=None, response_encoding=None,
        retry_on_timeout=None, retry_codes=None, **kwargs):
    return _make_request("GET", url,
                         retries=retries, back_off_factor=back_off_factor,
                         max_back_off=max_back_off,
                         timeout=timeout,
                         response_encoding=response_encoding,
                         retry_on_timeout=retry_on_timeout,
                         retry_codes=retry_codes,
                         **kwargs)
```

```
@patch('lib.httputil.get')
    def test_harvest(self, mock_get):
        articles = json.load(json_file)

        # Configure the mock to return a response with an OK status code. Also, the mock should have
        # a `json()` method that returns a list of todos.
        mock_get.return_value = Mock(ok=True)
        mock_get.return_value.json.return_value = articles
        mock_get.return_value.status_code = 200


        the_rest_of_the_test()
```

But I realized I need to mock it only if the URL is specific. I know I could use `new` keyword and do:

```
    def mock_get(self, url):
        if url == MY_SPECIFIC_URL:
            {...}
        else:
            self.old_get(url)


{...}

 with mock.patch('portality.lib.httputil.get', new=self.mock_get):
    the_rest_of_the_test()
```

but I don't really know how to mock the Response object so that it returns the correct status code and gives the correct result to `.json()` method.

How can I use both of these approaches altogether so that on one hand I can use the conditional but on the other mock the Response in easy way?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, along with [responses](https://github.com/getsentry/responses) which is specifically meant for returning the desired HTTP responses.

You can mock specific urls:

```
import responses
import requests

@responses.activate
def test_simple():
    responses.add(responses.GET, 'http://twitter.com/api/1/foobar',
                  json={'error': 'not found'}, status=404)

    resp = requests.get('http://twitter.com/api/1/foobar')

    assert resp.json() == {"error": "not found"}

    assert len(responses.calls) == 1
    assert responses.calls[0].request.url == 'http://twitter.com/api/1/foobar'
    assert responses.calls[0].response.text == '{"error": "not found"}'
```

And you can [exclude other urls](https://github.com/getsentry/responses#passing-through-real-requests):

```
responses.add_passthru(re.compile('https://percy.io/\\w+'))
```